# Is OpenHPI optional (not mandatory) to Pacemaker

Tags: debian, debian-jessie, pacemaker, corosync

I have noticed that `apt-get install -t jessie-backports pacemaker` on Debian Jessie 8.9 also installs package `openhpid`, but that `systemctl status openhpid.service` subsequently reports that the `openhpid.service` is not running, because no configuration has yet been provided in `/etc/openhpi/openhpi.conf`:

```
openhpid[17913]: ERROR: (init.c, 76, OpenHPI is not configured.  See openhpi.conf file.)
systemd[1]: openhpid.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=8/n/a
```

Is it correct to assume that [OpenHPI](http://openhpi.org) is optional (not mandatory) to the operation of Pacemaker (with Corosync) and that a running instance of `openhpid` is not needed (and the cited error message can be ignored)? I tend to believe this is the case partly because I have found no information on editing `openhpi.conf` in any of the Pacemaker tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct; you won't need to do anything with OpenHPI after installing in order to get a Pacemaker cluster going.

OpenHPI is a dependency of the `cluster-glue` package, which is a dependency of `pacemaker`, which is why it's getting installed.